# facebook Oauth error when posting photo from a HTTPS site (normal HTTP is fine)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, https, facebook-javascript-sdk

Getting an OAuth error doing a FB.api('/me/photos', 'post') on HTTPS, but works fine on HTTP.

```
Error occured:{"message":"An unknown error has occurred.","type":"OAuthException","code":1}
```

upload works:
http://sephoraframeworkapp.com

upload fails:
https://sephoraframeworkapp.com

CLICKING "FINISH" ON STEP4 does a call to FB.api('/me/photos','post'...etc) in order to POST a photo to the user's FB.

HTTP works FINE. however HTTPS FAILS!

```
FB.api('/photos', 'post', {
  message: 'Use the Sephora Framework app to transform pictures from your life into one extraordinary story. http://seph.me/SmcbkM',
  url: imgURL
}, function (response) {

  if (!response || response.error) {
      alert('Error occured:' + JSON.stringify(response.error));

  } else {
            FB.api('/'+response.id, function(response){
                storeSubmission(response.images[1].source);
            });
  }
 });
```

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: When you say 'fails' what do you mean? are you receiving an error?

Comment: Post the error you are getting

Comment: Error occured:{"message":"An unknown error has occurred.","type":"OAuthException","code":1}